# What is the end of string notation in python

Tags: python

I am from a c background. started learning python few days ago. my question is what is the end of string notation in python. like we are having `\0` in c. is there anything like that in python.

Comment: Why does this matter for a high-level programming like Python?

Comment: Python is not C and strings are objects not not simple pointers to some memory area.

Comment: Valid question but one that does not make much sense. Downvoted.

Comment: @user2799617 i mentioned that i am coming from c background. did not have much idea about python. to be clear about memory allocation in case of sting, i asked this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one. Python strings store the length of the string independent from the string contents.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like that in Python. A string is simply a string. The following:

```
test = "Hello, world!"
```

is simply a string of 13 characters. It's a self-contained object and it knows how many character it contains, there is no need for an end-of-string notation.

Answer (score 1):

Python's string management is internally a little more complex than that. Strings is a sequence type so that from a python coder's point of view it is more an array of characters than anything. (And so it has no terminating character but just a length property.)

If you must know: Internally python strings' data character arrays are null terminated. But the String object stores a couple of other properties as well. (e.g. the hash of the string for use as key in dictionaries.)

For more detailed info (especially for C coders) see here: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/